# Inline Interface implementation in Actionscript

Tags: actionscript, interface, implementation, inline

Is something like this possible in Actionscript?

Java:

```
URLFetcherFactory.setCreator(
    new IURLFetcherCreator() {
        public IURLFetcher create() {
            return new URLFetcher();
        }
    }
);
```

Actionscript:

```
?
```

I've been wondering about this and have been unable to find anything that indicates it's possible.  Figured if it *was* possible, I'd be able to find an answer here.  Thanks!  Stackoverflow rocks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create an instance of an interface. You can, however, create a factory class:

```
public class URLFetcherCreator : IURLFetcherCreator {
    private var _cls : Class;

    public URLFetcherCreator(Class cls) {
        this._cls = cls;
    }

    public function create() : IURLFetcher
    {
        return new cls();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, change setCreator to accept a Function that returns an IURLFetcher:

```
URLFetcherFactory.setCreator(
    function() : IURLFetcher {
        return new URLFetcher();
    }
);
```

Comment: Exactly!  I like the second implementation the best, even though you lose the ability to check what type the function returns.  That is more in-line with what I am trying to do.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame that AS3 doesn't support strongly typed delegates. Lambdas would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
URLFetcherFactory.setCreator(
    new IURLFetcherCreator() {
            public function create():IURLFetcher  {
                    return new URLFetcher();
            }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use anonymous inner classes in AS3.
For special cases like callbacks you can use Function instead of anonymous inner classes.

Java:

```
interface Callback {
     void done(String info);
}
class Service {
     void process(Callback callback);
}
...
myService.process(new Callback() {
     void done(String info) {
          // trace(info);
     }
}
```

AS3:

```
class Service {
     public function process(callback:Function):void;
}
...
myService.process(function(info:String):void {
     trace(info);
});
```